# can't get fb pages I like using graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I want only people who likes my fb page to access my website. But I am not getting the pages the users like. I am using opengraph api trough javascript.

This is what I am doing:

```
<script>
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
         document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into this app.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into Facebook.';
    }
}

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : <app_id>,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });

    FB.api('/me/likes', function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}

</script>
```

My problen is when I call `FB.api('/me/likes', function(response)` which returns `response = Object {data: Array[0]}`

what is wrong here?

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan sorry I just added more code to review

Comment: it is surely a late rply but have you tried it using the https in js.src